# google analytics gtag Event is not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to setup event tracking for google analytics.On form submit gtag event is not working .

```
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-1"></script>
 <script>
     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
     function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
     gtag('js', new Date());

     // gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-1');
     gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-1', {
         'custom_map': { 'dimension1': 'author_name' }
     });
     var form = document.getElementById('author-form');
     console.log(form);
     form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

         event.preventDefault();
         console.log('Event is submitted');
         gtag('event', 'article_view', { 'author_name': 'Ritwik B' });
         // gtag('event', 'author_form_complete', {
         //     'event_callback': function () {

         //         console.log('gtag');
         //         form.submit();

         //         console.log('gtag');
         //     }
         // });
     });
 </script>
```

'author_form_complete' event is works but when I check in **Real time-> Events** Tab there is no data.
please help.

Comment: is submit event getting executed. I don't see anything wrong with code. Almost same code is sending events for me.

Comment: @indolentdeveloper submit event is getting triggered and executed.but gtag doesn't trigger .there is some problem with gtag i think

Comment: how do you verify its is not working. Are you looking at live data on analytics page.

Comment: @indolentdeveloper Yes I'm checking.. I'm working in localhost.There it shows 0 active users on site.I don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: what host name are you using?

Comment: @indolentdeveloper book.com

Comment: check if domain is listed in site setting. Also for even localhost testing see that you use server. instead of directly access to file. There are also some other analytics debugging tools you can use those.

Comment: @indolentdeveloper I didn't get it

Comment: this code https://jsbin.com/sejugasica/edit?html works for me.